# How does the delay in data synchronization between chat and network sites happen?

Tags: support

https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and the individual sites has significant delay in data synchronization. For example [Stephen Kitt's chat account](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/140200/stephen-kitt) shows 997 bronze medals (and it was 996 yesterday),

[image]

while [his  network account](https://stackexchange.com/users/5117622/stephen-kitt) has shown 999 since yesterday:

[image]

How does the delay happen, while [the individual sites](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) don't have visible delay between themselves?

[image]

Is an implementation that can avoid the delay  too expensive?

I am interested in  data engineering, so I would like to hear data engineering side of the story

Thanks.

Comment: The answer will almost certainly be caching. Presumably, the chat profile is only updated periodically to avoid spamming the SE servers with API requests. You can usually find the answer here: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/ (this is a joke).

Comment: Interestingly, while the flair image is updated [every 24-36 hours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315442/10488700) and the (data behind the) chat profile page is updated [hourly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95424/410681), I'm still seeing 999 bronze badges in the former and 997 on the latter (surely not because of my local cache and likely not even because of IP-based server-side cache (if any)).

Comment: @fra-san I noticed the same thing, but forcing a local refresh updated the value on the chat profile, so it appears this *is* due to a local cache.

Comment: @StephenKitt I can't reproduce it anymore (I see you at 1000 everywhere now), but I'm quite sure I've seen 997 bronze badges both using a fresh browser session and requesting a screenshot of your chat profile to an online service (trying to also rule out a server-side caching issue).

Comment: @fra-san right, so it would appear that there are both server-side and local caches.

Comment: @StephenKitt your network silver medals are 888 now

Comment: @Tim so they are!